# Android: Floating Action Button (fab) with ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, floating-action-button

Is it possible to use a fab with an ExpandableListView? I know it is working with ListView, ScrollView and RecyclerView, but with my current library ([Github Link](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)) it is not possible to attach (fab.attachTo...()) it to an ExpandableListView.

Is there any alternative library that supports this, or is it actually possible with my current fab-library?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

[Expand a RecyclerView in Four Steps](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/)

[expandable-recycler-view](http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/)

with your fab.